App store notifications not receiving in react native iap
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getSubscriptions, initConnection, requestSubscription } from 'react-native-iap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { cancelPaymentOrderIdAction } from '../Actions/CommonActions';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { subscriptionPlans } from '../Constants';

const useIAP = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const userData = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.userData);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    initConnection();
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const productList = await getSubscriptions({ skus: subscriptionPlans });
        setProducts(productList);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('err', error)
      }
    };
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      fetchProducts();
    }
  }, []);

  const purchaseProductIOSProduct = async (
    productId,
    setLoadingData
  ) => {
    try {
      await requestSubscription({ sku: productId,appAccountToken:userData?.me?.id })
      .then(abc=>{
        console.log('abc',abc)
      }).catch(() => {
          dispatch(cancelPaymentOrderIdAction(null));
          setLoadingData(false);
        });
    } catch {
      dispatch(cancelPaymentOrderIdAction(null));
      setLoadingData(false);
    }
  };

  return { products, error, purchaseProductIOSProduct };
};

export default useIAP;


In screen component

useEffect(() => {
    const subscriptionPurchaseError = purchaseErrorListener((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

    const subscriptionUpdatedListener = purchaseUpdatedListener(
      async (purchase) => {
        const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
        if (receipt) {
          console.log('receipt',receipt)
          try {
            await finishTransaction({ purchase, isConsumable: false });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log("An error occurred while completing transaction", error);
          }
          validateIosPayment({
            variables: {
              input: {
                transactionId: purchase?.transactionId,
                receiptId: purchase?.transactionReceipt,
                id: createdOrderId,
              },
            },
          }).then(response => {
            if (
              response?.data?.validateIosPayment?.status ===
              PAYMENT_STATUS.SUCCESS
            ) {
              dispatch(cancelPaymentOrderIdAction(null));
              onPaymentSucessFull();
            }
            setLoadingData(false);
          }).catch(err=>{
            console.log('err',err)
            setLoadingData(false);
          });
        }
      });

    return () => {
      subscriptionPurchaseError.remove();
      subscriptionUpdatedListener.remove();
    };
  }, [createdOrderId]);

As the above code i am using and react native iap and buy a product as from product is consumable so i am hitting this function and kill the app. AS the payment is deducted but didn't get the plan. As the webhook is not firing. Then i tried purchase subscription plan in the also not getting webhook fire. So how can i get it done so that i will not miss any payment even user kill the app i will send a hit on backend to get a plan without any service with app store webhook. Please check and let me know where i am doing a mistake. I want to buy a consumable in app product and want a webhook and get userid as well in the webhook data.
